pgBackRest - optimal policy / setup for RPO of 1 hour
I need a bit of advice.
I have a postgres 14 database and a requirement for the DB, to be to recovered with RPO of 1 hour
(acceptable data loss is max of 1 hour).
Database size is 300 GB, backup size is 60GB. machine has 4 cores/32 RAM. The backup is executed on same machine as DB is.
I have set up a pgBackRest as a backup solution and GCS bucket as storage.
I execute it via crontab
I want to:

take a full backup every 24 hours
take a diff backup every hour

I have thought that would be enough. But actually the pgbackrest after creating the stanza, and making full backup, is constantly pushing WAL files to the GCS bucket. So maybe the diff backup is too much?
Do I really need the diff backup every hour?
I am asking because running it so often:

put an extra load on a system
If full backup is done let's say at 00:00 and does not finish in 1 hour (takes 3 hours) then it clashes with the diff backup and diff backup is not taken.

What are drawbacks of running just full backup every 24 hours and be happy that WAL files are constantly archived by postgresql archive_command = 'pgbackrest --stanza=main archive-push %p'
What is actually the benefit to have this diff backup every hour?
